# Sufficient statistic for finite Poisson mixture

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

We know the sum of independent observations is a [sufficient statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Poisson_distribution) for intensity parameter of the Poisson distribution.

My question: does there exist a sufficient statistic for a finite Poisson mixture?

For instance for the following Poisson mixture model with parameter $\lambda$  $(\Lambda=c \cdot \lambda$ and $c \ge 1$),

$$f(x)=p\frac{e^{-\lambda }  \lambda ^x}{x!}+(1-p)\frac{e^{-\Lambda }  \Lambda ^x}{x!}$$

taking two independent samples $x$ and $y$ we have,
$$f(x,y)=\frac{e^{-2 (\lambda +\Lambda)} \left(e^\lambda (p-1) \Lambda ^x-e^\Lambda p \lambda ^x\right) \left(e^\lambda (p-1) \Lambda ^y-e^\Lambda p \lambda ^y\right)}{x! y!}$$

Taking Log we have,
$$\log \left(\frac{e^{-2 (c+1) \lambda } \left(p e^{c \lambda } \lambda ^x-e^{\lambda} (p-1) (c \lambda)^x\right) \left(p e^{c \lambda} \lambda^y-e^{\lambda} (p-1) (c \lambda)^y\right)}{x! y!}\right) \\ =  -\log (x! y!)+\log \left(e^{-2 (c \lambda +\lambda)}\right)+\log \left((e^{\lambda} (p-1) (c \lambda)^x - p e^{c \lambda} \lambda ^x\right)\left(e^\lambda (p-1) (c \lambda)^y -p e^{c \lambda} \lambda^y)\right) \\ =\boxed{-\log (x! y!)+\log \left(e^{-2 (c \lambda +\lambda)}\right)+\log \left( e^{2c\lambda} p^2\lambda^{(x+y)} + e^{-2c\lambda+\lambda}(1-p)p c^y \lambda^{(x+y)}+{}\\ e^{\lambda-c\lambda}(1-p)c^xp\lambda^{(x+y)}+e^{2\lambda}(1-p)^{2}c^{(x+y)}\lambda^{(x+y)} \right)}$$

In above equation it looks like parameter $\lambda$ is interacting with the data only through $(x+y)$, that means sum of data is sufficient statistic for finite Poisson mixture too.  Is this correct?

Comment: Are you dealing with a family of distributions indexed by three parameters, $\lambda,$ $\Lambda,$ and $p$? Or do you take $p$ to be fixed (thus "known")? Or are you only trying to estimate $p$ with $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$ fixed? Or what?

Comment: $p$ is known. $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$ are known too, but don't know which of the two is true.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to speak of a sufficient statistic when everything is known, unless it's a completely trivial sufficient statistic equal, for example to $1$ regardless of the data. To say everything is known means there is only one probability distribution in your family of distributions. A sufficient statistic $T$ is a function of the data $X$ for which the conditional distribution of $X$ given $T$ is the same for all distributions in the family. But if there's only one distribution in the family, then that becomes a triviality.

Comment: That's cool to know another way to look at sufficient statistic. I think, I didn't put clearly. Let me say again: $p$ is some fixed constant and its a probability of $\lambda$( another known constant) and  $(1-p)$ is some fixed constant and its a probability of $\Lambda$(known constant).

Comment: Do you have in mind $(1)$ a family of distributions parametrized by $p,$ $\lambda,$ and $\Lambda,$ or $(2)$ a family of distributions parametrized by $p$ and $\lambda$ with $\Lambda$ fixed, or $(3)$ a family of distributions parametrized by $p$ and $\Lambda$ with $\lambda$ fixed, or $(4)$ a family of distributions parametrized by $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$ with $p$ fixed, or $(5)$ a family of distribution parametrized by $p$ with $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$ fixed, or $(6)$ a family of distributions parametrized by $\lambda$ with $p$ and $\Lambda$ fixed, or$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$or $(7)$ a family of distributions parametrized by $\Lambda$ with $p$ and $\lambda$ fixed, or $(8)$ something else? $\qquad$

Comment: I'm interested in understanding the two cases of $(1)$ and $(4)$.